# Z-Index / Scrolling issue in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a blog that I'm having a slight styling (CSS) issue in Chrome only. For reference the blog is located [here](http://usdish.com/blog/).

The issue is that (in Chrome only) when I scroll the content should go under the nav bar (but over the top of the big image), but it goes over. Again, this issue only exists in Chrome.

I'm not sure where to even start, but I'm hoping y'all will have a few tips for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually fairly simple and had to do with the `positioning` of the `header elements`.

**I changed** `#header_area .page` to `position: absolute`, and `#header_area .Nav` to `position: fixed`. I also gave `#header_area .header a` `top margin` of `70px` and made that `position: fixed` as well.